# How can I detect the first and the last element inside a foreach loop?

Tags: php

I want to detect the first and the last element inside a foreach loop:

```
$path = "monkey/cat/horse";

foreach(explode('/', $path) as $segment) {
   echo $segment;
}
```

My desired result is:

```
first:monkey
last:horse
```

This is how I tried to solve it:

```
$path = "monkey/cat/horse";
$explode = explode('/', $path);

foreach($explode as $segment) {
    if (current($explode) == $segment){
        echo "first:".$segment;
    } echo "<br>";
    if (end($explode) == $segment){
        echo "last:".$segment;
    }
}
```

But my result is:

```
first:horse
last:horse
```

Comment: you can simply do it....

Comment: `array_pop` and `array_shift` may help you

Comment: Best way will be [`reset($arr)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php) and [`end($arr)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.end.php), this will prevent you from editing your array but I don't think you care about this. [`$explode = explode('/', $path); echo reset($explode); echo end($explode);`](https://eval.in/559901)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No need of foreach loop, just use a `foreach` loop and `count`. the foreach loop return an array.

```
$path = "monkey/cat/horse";

$arr = explode("/", $path);
$count = count($arr);


foreach($arr as $key => $value){
    if($key == 0) echo "first:".$value;
    elseif($key == ($count - 1)) echo "last:".$value;
}
```

**Result**

```
first:monkey
last:horse
```

Comment: It must be inside a for each loop, because I need the loop for something else

Comment: @Jarla, I update my answer with foreach loop, Check and let me know.

Answer (score 3):

This works as fine.

```
$path = "monkey/cat/horse";
$explode = explode('/', $path);


echo "first:".current($explode);

echo "<br>";

echo "last:".end($explode);
```

WITH LOOP:

```
$path = "monkey/cat/horse";
$explode = explode('/', $path);
$cont = 0;

foreach($explode as $segment) {

    if ($cont == 0){

        echo "first:".$segment;
    } 

    echo "<br>";

    if ($cont > count($segment)){

        echo "last:".$segment;
    }

    $cont = $cont +1;
}
```

Comment: yes, because you removed the loop, which is necessary for me

Answer (score 1):

Get length of the array.

Get a counter and increment it over foreach.

In the loop:

1) if counter is `0`, its first element.

2) If counter is array count minus one, its the last element.

```
<?php
$path = "monkey/cat/horse";
$explode = explode('/', $path);
$len = count($explode);
$i=0;
foreach($explode as $segment) {
 if ($i == 0) {
    echo "first: ".$segment;
    echo "<br/>";
 }
 if ($i == ($len-1)) {
    echo "last: ".$segment;
 }
 ++$i;
}
?>
```

Output:

```
first: monkey
last: horse
```

[Live demo](https://eval.in/559882)

Comment: Thank you very much! This is working. I tried to add an `else` for all other cases `if ($i == 0) {
    echo "first:".$segment;
    echo "<br/>";
 }
 if ($i == ($len-1)) {
    echo "last:".$segment;
 } else { echo "others:".$segment;}`

Comment: But here I get also for the first element `other`

Comment: @Jarla you have a mistake: the `else` only refers to the second `if`.

Comment: I have updated the answer with working url. Please go to the url and check if its working.

Comment: @AlessioCantarella Thank you. Well, Ineed to find out how to refer to both if`s. Never did that before :=)

Answer (score 1):

your code has only a little problem, try to change the current function by reset function. Like this:

```
$path = "monkey/cat/horse";
$explode = explode('/', $path);
foreach($explode as $segment) {

    if (reset($explode) == $segment){
        echo "first: $segment";
    }

    echo "<br>";

    if (end($explode) == $segment){
        echo "last: $segment";
    }
}
```

Here you are the reference about "reset" function:
http://php.net/manual/es/function.reset.php

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?php

  $path = "monkey/cat/horse";

  $arr = explode("/", $path);


$data= $arr;
echo end($data);  //last value
echo reset($data);  //firast value
?>
```